# Fetching array of data from DB using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to access multiple columns using Rails 3.But it gave me the following error.

> Error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:13:in `check_type'
```

Check my below code.

> payment_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

    def payment
        @payment=Vendor.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html 
            format.js
        end

    end
    def check_type  
        if params[:commit]=="submit"
           @vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck(:type ,:Receipt_No)
           @vendor_type.each do |vendor|

            end
        else
            @v_name=Vendor.where(:s_catagory => params[:payment][:s_catagory] ).pluck(:v_name)
        end
    end
end
```

Actually i want to retrive data like below format.

```
@vendor_type=["Receipt_no":"type","Receipt_no":"type",.....]
```

Once these data will appear,I need how to access row values according to Receipt_No.Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **ActiveRecord >= 4** . `pluck` accepts multiple arguments so in

**Rails 4:** Your query will work

```
@vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck(:type ,:Receipt_No)
```

---

Now as you are using **Rails 3** which doesn't support multiple arguments to `pluck` then we can extend `ActiveRecord::Relation` itself like this:

put your file under **config/initializers**

```
# pluck_all.rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    def pluck_all(*args)
      args.map! do |column_name|
        if column_name.is_a?(Symbol) && column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
          "#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}"
        else
          column_name.to_s
        end
      end

      relation = clone
      relation.select_values = args
      klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel).map! do |attributes|
        initialized_attributes = klass.initialize_attributes(attributes)
        attributes.each do |key, attribute|
          attributes[key] = klass.type_cast_attribute(key, initialized_attributes)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your controller you can pass multiple arguments to `pluck` like this:

```
# payment_controller.rb:
@vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).pluck_all(:type ,:Receipt_No)
```

Now you can use `pluck_all` in whole app. Hope this helps ;)

**EDIT:**
Try below code if `plcuk_all` not worked:

```
@vendor_type = PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).map{|v|[v.type ,v.Receipt_No]}
```

Reference for more info: http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/

Comment: @ Gagan: Your answer is always helpful and hope..it will help me a lot.I cannot implement right now..i will update you tomorrow..

Comment: @ Gagan : I did as per you defined but still it is giving me the error as-NoMethodError (undefined method `pluck_all' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x20274
78>):.Please help me to resolve this error..

Comment: @rajat_474 : I have to checkout with Rails 3. Currently you can use `jon snow` answer or refer provided link. I will test it myself then will let u update. Till that time you can use other solution.

Comment: Ok...i am trying  to use jon's method.

Comment: @ Gagan ,Do you have any other solution for this?

Comment: @rajat_474 : Check my updated answer. I have put `Edit` for you

Comment: @ Gagan :Have you checked jon's method ?it was same as your line.I have put the comment also.Please check.

Comment: it's all bcz I already told you make a habit of giving table attribute's name properly. attribute name should not start with capital. And this is a error of Single table inheritance. So have to check your all associations and table structure. I checked this query in my app and returns as per expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76424/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-gagan-gami).

Comment: if you have difficulty implementing #`pluck_all` method, try [pluck_all](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all) gem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pluck(:type ,:Receipt_No)` looks wrong,
pluck have only one argument.

Also your type of data `@vendor_type` is wrong, Array don't have `key, value` pair.

Use `map` like this,

```
@vendor_type=PaymentVendor.where(:v_name => params[:v_name]).map { |i| [i.Receipt_No] }
```

Comment: pluck support multiple columns from rails 4 but only one in rails 3

Comment: @Ian : So Is there any other way to access multiple column in Rails 3?

Comment: Array don't have key, value pair. your expected `@vendor_type` is wrong.

Comment: you could look at http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/select

Comment: use `map` to get your expected one.

Comment: @jon :I applied your line but it is throwing this error.
Error:

ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound (The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to
 locate the subclass: 'SWD'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is r
eserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename this column
if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or overwrit
e PaymentVendor.inheritance_column to use another column for that information.):

Comment: @rajat_474 ok, removed

Answer (score 0):

In terms of making a rails 3 method that behaves the same as the Rails 4 pluck with multiple columns. This outputs a similar array (rather than a hashed key value collection). This should save a bit of pain if you ever come to upgrade and want to clean up the code.

See this [tutorial](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/) which outlines a similar method that outputs a hash.

```
config/initializers/pluck_all.rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    def pluck_all(*args)
      args.map! do |column_name|
        if column_name.is_a?(Symbol) && column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
          "#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}"
        else
          column_name.to_s
        end
      end

      relation = clone
      relation.select_values = args
      klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel).map! do |attributes|
        initialized_attributes = klass.initialize_attributes(attributes)
        attributes.map do |key, attribute|
          klass.type_cast_attribute(key, initialized_attributes)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Standing on the shoulders of giants and all